# Where are the contents of WP_Head

Tags: css, headers, wp-head

I'm building a theme based on underscores. In the header I'm finding some code for a `margin-top` but I can't seem to find the source in order to get rid of it. I looked in functions hoping it was defined there, but I actually can't find anything in the theme

```
@media screen and (max-width: 782px)
html {
  margin-top: 46px !important;
}
```

I saw that someone suggested adding a new style to the header after `<?php wp_head(); ?>`. I'll do that if that's what it takes, but let me know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the source of my problem is a function called `admin_bar_bump`in wp-includes>admin-bar.php. It's for the admin bar and when I log out it goes away so it wasn't effecting the style of the site for logged out users.

I was able to filter it out in my functions.php file. That's actually no better than adding a style to the header, but at least I know where it was coming from.